# Chart with custom metrics of pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: charts, tfs, azure-devops

I need to display chart with a metric (e.g. accuracy) after every build or release in TFS. Metric is calculated during pipeline execution.

And now I don't know can I put the number into TFS/Azure somehow in standard manner and can I display chart based on the number?

Comment: Do you want to display the chart on the dashboard?

Comment: Yes, if it is possible.

Comment: Did you managed to find something about this in the end? I need something similar too! :)

Comment: @Cata, I did not find the solution yet.